# solving this question based on homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> The function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\varphi(a)=a+1$ is an isomorphism. True or False.

**Solution**

True

Because I solve using the definition of isomorphism that is bijection
So I prove first that the function is one to one
Given $\varphi(a)= a+1$ show that $a=b$ then the function then $a+1=b+1$ cancel the $1$ and I got $a=b$

Then I prove that is onto using $g(x)=y$ and $y=x+1$, and then add $-1$ by both sides and got $x=y-1$ and call it $g(x)=y-1$,then putting back and solved it I got $g(x)=y$ so it onto.

But the answer is False Why?
Any reason 
ok

Correction
Solution
So the solution look like this
$\varphi(g1+g2)= \varphi(g1)+ \varphi(g2)$
then
$\varphi(g1)=x1+1$
$\varphi(g2)=x2+1$
So
$\varphi(g1+g2)=\varphi(x1+1+x2+1)=\varphi(x1+x2+2)$
therefore is not follow the definition so it false
it that correct or not?

Comment: Isomorphism in what sense? Group, ring, field, vector space? In general, an isomorphism is a bijection *that preserves algebraic structure*, so just showing it's a bijection is insufficient.

Comment: Be sure to include the dollar sign when typing in $\LaTeX$

Comment: Do you know the properties of homomorphism?

Comment: \varphi(g1g2)=\varphi(gi)\varphi(g2) that what it means

Comment: In the range of $\varphi$, you want $\varphi(g_1 + g_2) = \varphi(g_1) + \varphi(g_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are talking about $\phi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as a field isomorphism.  Certainly, the map you have been given is bijective.  However, it is not a proper homomorphism.  Remember that homomorphisms must preserve the following properties:

$$\phi(a+b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$$
$$\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$$

Well, let $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

$$\phi(0 \cdot 1) = \phi(0) = 1 \neq \phi(0)\phi(1) = 2$$.

We conclude that $\phi$ is *not* an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

$\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $\varphi(a)=a+1$, is not isomorphism beacuse it is not a homomorphism.. in fact $\varphi(c+d)\neq \varphi(c)+\varphi(d)$ $$\varphi(c+d)=c+d+1 \text{ , }\varphi(c)+\varphi(d)=c+1+d+1=c+d+2 \to \varphi(c+d)\neq \varphi(c)+\varphi(d)$$